# Yii2 call the console command not from the project folder

Tags: php, linux, yii2, console

## Hello. I created the console command in Yii2:

```
projectDir/commands/SomeController.php
        
<?php
namespace app\commands;
            
use yii\console\Controller;

/**
 * Class SomeController
 * @package app\commands
 */
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function actionTest()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I want to call this command in cron,and for testing I try to call it from the console, when I'm in the project folder:

```
php /var/www/projectDir/yii some/test
```

Everything works fine. But, if I call this command when I'm in a different directory, I get some errors.

First, i got

```
ReflectionException: Class app\admin\templates\Generator does not exist in /var/www/projectDir/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:428
```

Seeing this, I commented configuration of gii in the file `projectDir/common/config/config-console.php`

After that I get an error:

```
Unknown command: some/test
```

Why is this happening?
I call the command with an absolute path, and it works differently when called from different folders!

Comment: You're probably using relive paths in your configuration. How did you defined `@app` alias? How does this commented Gii config looks like?

Comment: @rob006 Indeed, in the configuration files I found such constructions (the project was not written by me):
`$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db/db.php');` and `$config['basePath'] = realpath('../../')`

How can I rewrite this with bestPractice? Or is the answer too dependent on the project?

Comment: @rob006 about Gii:
config-console has this:
`'templates' => [ 'theme' => '@app/admin/templates/theme']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use magic constant `__DIR__` to build absolute paths. Result of `realpath('../../')` will depend on path where you run command. You should use

```
$config['basePath'] = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../')
```

or (probably better):

```
$config['basePath'] = dirname(dirname(__DIR__))
```